# How can I add a user/AD Group to SP when the people picker won't display more that 30 results?

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker, ad, spgroup

One customer has to add an AD Group to a SharePoint group and there are more than 30 other AD groups in their directory whose name is quite similar.

Of the 30 matches found by the people picker, none of them is the desired AD group and SharePoint 2016 isn't giving me the mean to select the one I want because the people picker won't display more than 30 suggestions.

Apparently, the name of the desired AD group has only three letters and there are more than 30 AD group whose name begin with those letters. E.g.: they are looking to add the AD group whose name is just "IDS" but there are more that 30 groups whose name begin with...IDS. The people picker won't display the one with just three letters.

If this was 2010 I would have used the very functional address book.

How can I add the AD group to a SharePoint group in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious workaround is to just type more. The more letters you type of the group name, the more distinct the query becomes and the more likely it is to return less than 30 results from AD.

In addition, changing the group name will make everything more efficient if circumstances permit.

Comment: Thank you. I will improve my initial question, because the problem apparently is that they are trying to add an AD group whose name has just three letters (something like domain\IDS) and there are more than 30 AD groups that begin precisely with IDS (e.g.: IDS_researchers, IDS_account; I'm making these names up).

Comment: By design, we can't change the maximum limit for the People Selection field – 30
If circumstances permit, I still recommend that you change the group name to make it easier to find.
You can change it to something like: IDS_domain
In addition, you can try to add an AD group to sharepoint group using the power shell command:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0301b79-ab41-426d-988f-f6ea4168de57/how-to-programmatically-add-an-ad-group-to-a-sharepoint-group?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: Any progress on your troubleshooting?

Comment: Nope, ultimately they will have to suck it and either change the names of the groups or use a PowerShell script just to manage the permissions of those groups whose name is less than three characters.